# Generate Random password and send to email in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

when you register on my site your password is stored using $hashedPass = md5($password);.

the below code is my forgot password code :

**Problem is : its redirect to denied page.**

Friends may i know where i made a mistake in the below code 
Please Help me Friends

```
<?php
session_start();  // Start Session
//Connect to the database through our include 
    include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
session_register("session");
// This is displayed if all the fields are not filled in
$empty_fields_message = "<p>Please go back and complete all the fields in the form.</p>Click <a class=\"two\" href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">here</a> to go back";
// Convert to simple variables  
$email = $_POST['email'];
if (!isset($_POST['email'])) {

?>
       <?php
}
elseif (empty($email)) {
    echo $empty_fields_message;
}
else {
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$status = "OK";
$msg="";
//error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR);
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
$msg="Your email address is not correct<BR>"; 
$status= "NOTOK";}

echo "<br><br>";
if($status=="OK"){  $query="SELECT email,username FROM members WHERE email = '$email'";
$st=mysql_query($query);
$recs=mysql_num_rows($st);
$row=mysql_fetch_object($st);
$em=$row->email;// email is stored to a variable
 if ($recs == 0) {
//Redirect to denied page.
 print "<script language='Javascript'>document.location.replace('forgotenpass_denied.php');</script>";
}
function makeRandomPassword() { 
          $salt = "abchefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789"; 
          srand((double)microtime()*1000000);  
          $i = 0; 
          while ($i <= 7) { 
                $num = rand() % 33; 
                $tmp = substr($salt, $num, 1); 
                $pass = $pass . $tmp; 
                $i++; 
          } 
          return $pass; 
    } 
    $random_password = makeRandomPassword();  
    $password = md5($random_password); 

    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET password='$password'  WHERE email='$email'"); 

     $to = "$email";
    // Change this to your site admin email
    $from = "geetha.victor@tryteksolutions.com";
    $subject = "Your Password Has been reset"; 
    $message = "Hi, we have reset your password. 

    Your New Password is: $random_password 

    http://www.trytek.tryteksolutions.co.in/login.php
    Once logged in you can change your password 

    Thanks! 
    Admin 

    This is an automated response, DO NOT REPLY!"; 

   $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
        $to = "$to";
        // Finally send the activation email to the member
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    print "<script language='Javascript'>document.location.replace('forgotenpass_sucess.php');</script>"; 
 } 
 else {echo "<center><font face='Verdana' size='2' color=red >$msg <br><br><input type='button' value='Retry' onClick='history.go(-1)'></center></font>";}
}
?>
```

Comment: why you can't use php header function? for redirection to another page...

Comment: Are u seeing forgotenpass_sucess.php after the re-direct ?

Comment: Should it be spelt forgottenpass_sucess.php ? (your script has one 't' in the filename)

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Yes

Comment: may be its path related issue ? what url u see after the re-direct ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty my code to create random password and send to email but my code is strucking in forgot password denied its not coming to generate password and send email

Answer (score 2):

There is so much wrong here, that I barely know where to start.

1. As documented under [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/function.mysql-num-rows#refsect1-function.mysql-num-rows-returnvalues):

   > #### Return Values
   >
   > The number of rows in a result set on success or `FALSE` on failure.

   As documented under [PHP type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), `FALSE == 0` is true.  Therefore, the boolean expression `$recs == 0` will evaluate to `TRUE` even if `mysql_num_rows()` failed.  You must instead use a strict comparison `$recs === 0` to ensure that it only evaluates to `TRUE` if its value is a zero.

   You should also check whether function calls failed and, if they did, perform suitable error handling.  For example:

   ```
   mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
   ```
2. That said, as documented under `mysql_query()`:

   > #### Warning
   >
   > This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
   >
   > - [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
   > - [`PDO::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)
3. As documented under [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double):

   > #### Double quoted
   >
   > If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret more escape sequences for special characters:
   >
   > ```
   > ╔════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
   > ║      Sequence      ║                                              Meaning                                              ║
   > ╠════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
   > ║ \n                 ║ linefeed (LF or 0x0A (10) in ASCII)                                                               ║
   > ║ \r                 ║ carriage return (CR or 0x0D (13) in ASCII)                                                        ║
   > ║ \t                 ║ horizontal tab (HT or 0x09 (9) in ASCII)                                                          ║
   > ║ \v                 ║ vertical tab (VT or 0x0B (11) in ASCII) (since PHP 5.2.5)                                         ║
   > ║ \e                 ║ escape (ESC or 0x1B (27) in ASCII) (since PHP 5.4.0)                                              ║
   > ║ \f                 ║ form feed (FF or 0x0C (12) in ASCII) (since PHP 5.2.5)                                            ║
   > ║ \\                 ║ backslash                                                                                         ║
   > ║ \$                 ║ dollar sign                                                                                       ║
   > ║ \"                 ║ double-quote                                                                                      ║
   > ║ \[0-7]{1,3}        ║ the sequence of characters matching the regular expression is a character in octal notation       ║
   > ║ \x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2} ║ the sequence of characters matching the regular expression is a character in hexadecimal notation ║
   > ╚════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
   > ```
   >
   > As in single quoted strings, escaping any other character will result in the backslash being printed too.

   Your string `"/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/"` therefore relies on the fact that `\w`, `\-`, `\@` and `\.` are not valid double-quoted string escape sequences.  You should at very least escape the backslashes in order to explicitly include them in the regular expression:

   ```
   if (!preg_match("/([\\w\\-]+\\@[\\w\\-]+\\.[\\w\\-]+)/",$email)) {
   ```

   That said, since `@` is not a [PCRE meta-character](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) it actually does not need to be escaped.

   Furthermore, the character class `[\w\-]` encompasses letters, digits, underscores and hyphens: which is not sufficient to match an email address—look at [some examples of valid email addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses) to see why; indeed, regular expressions [cannot be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378) to validate email addresses (one should use a parser instead).

   However, in your case, I don't see why it is necessary to validate the email address at all—just go straight into looking it up in your database.
4. As documented under [`md5()`](http://php.net/md5):

   > #### Note: Secure password hashing
   >
   > It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash) for details.
5. Others have already observed that you can (and probably should) redirect using HTTP headers rather than JavaScript.
6. There are a bunch of other oddities:

   ```
   $row=mysql_fetch_object($st);
   $em=$row->email;// email is stored to a variable
   ```

   It is not clear why you do this: after all, you already have the value of `$em` in `$email`.  Also, bear in mind that your query may have returned more than one record, whereas this will only fetch the first one thereof.

   ```
   $to = "$email";
   ```

   Why not just `$to = $email` (or indeed, just use `$email` directly as the `mail()` function call's first argument)?  You're requiring the PHP to undertake unnecessary parsing in order to perform a simple assignment.  For that matter, you are using double-quoted string literals throughout your code where single-quoted literals (that have less parsing overhead and protect you from accidentally including unescaped variables) would suffice.

   ```
   $to = "$to";
   ```

   I have no idea what could be the purpose of this line of code.

   ```
   $status = "OK";
   $status= "NOTOK";
   if($status=="OK")
   ```

   Why not use a boolean instead of string comparison?
7. In this day & age, one *really* ought to be using CSS instead of `<center>`, `<font>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the full server path for

```
print "<script language='Javascript'>document.location.replace('forgotenpass_denied.php');</script>";
```

and

```
print "<script language='Javascript'>document.location.replace('forgotenpass_sucess.php');</script>";
```

Instead of using

```
document.location.replace('forgotenpass_denied.php')
```

Try

```
document.location.replace('/home/xxxxx/www/forgotenpass_denied.php')
```

Comment: Javascript code isn't going to work with full file paths...unless his document root is set to his root directory.

Comment: that what I was hoping for :)

Comment: I sure hope that is not the case

Comment: @ginovva320 my code is to create random password and send to email but my code is strucking in forgot password denied its not coming to generate password and send email

Answer (score 0):

The problem is obviously somewhere in this block:

```
$query="SELECT email,username FROM members WHERE email = '$email'";
$st=mysql_query($query);
$recs=mysql_num_rows($st);
$row=mysql_fetch_object($st);
$em=$row->email;// email is stored to a variable
 if ($recs == 0) {
//Redirect to denied page.
 print "<script language='Javascript'>document.location.replace('forgotenpass_denied.php');</script>";
}
```

More specifically, the problem is that your query is returning `0` records (or `FALSE` on error). Unfortunately, my crystal ball is out of order, so I can't tell you why. Nevertheless, here are some things to verify:

- Do you have a working database connection?
- Do the table/field names in the query match the database schema?
- Does `$email` actually exists in table `members`?

Comment: column in table members are: username, password, email

Comment: include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";

Comment: Just in case, make this small change before proceeding: `$st=mysql_query($query) or die("Database error");`